# Problem with inequality in Apostol's Calculus I Method of Exhaustion.

Tags: calculus

I am looking through T. M Apostols Calculus I and just at the introduction (Pg 5 and 6), I can't seem to understand the very first proof. My problem is how he deduced the inequality $$1^2 + 2^2 +\cdots+ (n-1)^2 < \frac{n^3}{3}< 1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + n^2$$ from the two equations $$1^2 + 2^2 +\cdots+ (n-1)^2 = \frac{n^3}{3}-\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}$$ and $$1^2 + 2^2 +\cdots+ n^2 = \frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}$$

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{n^3}{3}-\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}<\frac{n^3}{3}<\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}=1+2^2+...+n^2$$

Comment: The RHS inequality is fine but the LHS inequality is not immediately obvious to me. Can you please expantiate how you obtained $\frac{n^3}{n} - \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{6} <\frac{n^3}{3}$

Comment: $\frac{n}{6}-\frac{n^2}{2}<0$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$